# Routing Static Pages in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having some difficulty figuring out how to route static pages in rails 4. I have created a controller called `PagesController` and so I also have a views folder called `pages` with the oakville.html.erb file in it.

My controller looks like this:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

    def our_mission
    end

end
```

My routes file looks like this:

```
get "oakville", :to => "pages#oakville"
```

I am assuming that I should be able to get to this page by going to localhost:3000/oakville  ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods in your controller are called actions, and for each static page that you want to be able to navigate to you will need a corresponding controller action. When a person (or link) navigates to `yoursite/oakville` your routes file needs to know which controller action to perform for the oakville branch of the url.

In the routes that you have shown, `get "oakville", :to => "pages#oakville"` you are asking the controller to render the `oakville` action. But there is no `oakville` action in your controller. Add one and problem solved:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def our_mission
  end

  def oakville
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have done everything as suggested however when I go to the page it now says "This webpage has a redirect loop".

Comment: Can you show more of your routes file related to the Pages controller, or more of your Pages controller if there is anything you left out?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you need to add a controller action for oakville

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

    def oakville
    end

end
```

Also, you will need to create `oakville.html.erb` and put this into your `views/pages` directory

Answer (score 0):

The route you've shown and the action you've shown are completely unrelated.

If you want to route a url like `http://www.example.com/oakville` to an action called `our_mission` on the `Pages` controller, the route looks like this:

```
get 'oakville' => 'pages#our_mission'
```

What you've written indicates you expect an action called `oakville` to exist, and according to the code you've provided, it doesn't.